# Laravel Inertia prop not passing values

Tags: laravel, vuejs3, inertiajs

When calling an edit function the prop mealService is passing null values and will not populate form fields with values. It looks like the controller isn't loading the model to query the single record. The Create and Store functions work fine.

First time posting. And very new to coding. Please let me know if more info is needed for the question.

edit.vue

```
export default {
  components: {
    Head,
    Link,
    LoadingButton,
    SelectInput,
    TrashedMessage,
  },
  layout: Layout,
  props: {
    mealService: Object,
    sites: Array,
  },
  remember: 'form',
  data() {
    return {
      form: this.$inertia.form({
        site_id: this.mealService.site_id,
        meal_type: this.mealService.meal_type,
        adults: this.mealService.adults,
        tally: this.mealService.tally,       
      }),
    }
  },
```

MealServiceController

```
public function edit(MealService $meal_service)
    {
        return Inertia::render('MealServices/Edit', [
            'mealService' => [
                'id' => $meal_service->id,
                'site_id' => $meal_service->site_id,
                'meal_type' => $meal_service->meal_type,
                'adults' => $meal_service->adults,
                'tally' => $meal_service->tally,
            ],
            'sites' => Auth::user()->sfa
                ->sites()
                ->orderBy('name')
                ->get()
                ->map
                ->only('id', 'name'),
        ]);
    }
```

MealService Model

```
class MealService extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    use SoftDeletes;

    public function resolveRouteBinding($value, $field = null)
        {
            return $this->where($field ?? 'id', $value)->withTrashed()->firstOrFail();
        }

    public function site()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Site::class);
    }

    public function scopeFilter($query, array $filters)
    {
        $query->when($filters['search'] ?? null, function ($query, $search) {
            $query->WhereHas('site', function ($query) use ($search) {
                $query->where('name', 'like', '%'.$search.'%');
            });
        })->when($filters['trashed'] ?? null, function ($query, $trashed) {
            if ($trashed === 'with') {
                $query->withTrashed();
            } elseif ($trashed === 'only') {
                $query->onlyTrashed();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Route

```
Route::get('mealServices/{mealService}/edit', [MealServicesController::class, 'edit'])
->name('mealServices.edit')
->middleware('auth');
```

Comment: Can you see if the XHR request brings up the data you have sent via controller to inertia?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your edit function you are using `meal_service` while in your route you use `mealService`

Try naming the one in the edit function `mealService` too